# エラー複数…Could not delete path,Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Android Studio にて開発中に多くのエラーが発生しました。
いくつかのサイトを参考に対処試みましたが解決できません。

Android Studio のアンインストール、 JDK のインストール等行いましたが効果なしです。
毎回エラーが発生するわけではなく、 3 回に 1 回程の頻度なので訳が分かりません。
もちろんクリーンビルド、キャッシュの削除は行いました。

エラー内容のみ公開していますが、必要なソースコードがありましたら掲載いたします。

どなたか助けてください…。

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\Timer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ca'.
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:392)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: Error: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\Timer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ca'.
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:481)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:46)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:238)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:412)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doIncrementalTaskAction(MergeResources.java:381)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\Timer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ca'.
    at com.android.utils.FileUtils.deletePath(FileUtils.java:68)
    at com.android.utils.FileUtils.deleteDirectoryContents(FileUtils.java:84)
    at com.android.utils.FileUtils.cleanOutputDir(FileUtils.java:111)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:479)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: `C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\Timer\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-ca`が削除できない旨のエラーメッセージになっていますが、このエラーが発生した際に、エクスプローラから手動で該当ファイルを削除しようとするとどうなるでしょうか。(おそらく他のプロセスが開いているため削除できないというダイアログが出ると思いますが、そのプロセスは何でしょうか。例えばアンチウィルスソフトが開いているのであれば、プロジェクトディレクトリをチェック対象から外す、といった方法で対処できると思います。)

Comment: 地道に指定されたフォルダを削除することで実行することができるようになりました！しかし、少しレイアウトを変化させるとまた同じようなエラーが出てその都度フォルダを削除しています。このエラーの根源が知りたいです…。

Comment: 常駐プロセスでファイル変更を監視しているようなものがあればそのような状況が発生し得るかと考えます。ありがちなのは、アンチウィルスソフトで、対策としては当ディレクトリを監視対象から除外する、といったことが考えられます。